# How to filter characters in an EditText

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to create an IInputFilter for an EditText in my Xamarin Android app.  I created the class below to do this.  It works fine until I enter an invalid character.  It filters the invalid character as expected, but after that the source includes all valid characters entered since the invalid one.

Key "a" - source = "a"

Key "b" - source = "b"

Key "," - source = "," (this is an invalid character so we return empty string)

Key "c" - source = "c"

Key "d" - source = "cd" (why not just "d"?)

Key "e" - source = "cde" (and so on)

```
public class AlphaFilter : Java.Lang.Object, IInputFilter
{
    public Java.Lang.ICharSequence FilterFormatted(Java.Lang.ICharSequence source, int start, int end, ISpanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {
        Java.Lang.String strResult;
        bool blnValidated = source.ToString() == string.Empty || source.ToString().All(Char.IsLetterOrDigit);

        if (blnValidated)
        {
            strResult = new Java.Lang.String(source.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            strResult = new Java.Lang.String(string.Empty);
        }
        return strResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you testing for `blnValidated || dest.ToString().Equals("")`?  This means that if the dest is empty it doesn't matter if the input is valid or not

Comment: My understanding is that if the user hits the backspace the dest will be empty so you have to allow that through.  I was planning to test all that out once I get the normal validation working.

Comment: Correction, it's source that is empty when the backspace is used.  Corrected OP to check that instead.  Original problem still exists.  Once an invalid character is entered, source returns all characters entered since invalid character.

Comment: have you just stepped through it in the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.  When the character is valid you just return null.  Here is the working code:

```
    public class AlphanumericFilter : Java.Lang.Object, IInputFilter
{
    public Java.Lang.ICharSequence FilterFormatted(Java.Lang.ICharSequence source, int start, int end, ISpanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {
        Java.Lang.String strResult;
        bool blnValidated = source.ToString() == string.Empty || source.ToString().All(Char.IsLetterOrDigit);

        if (blnValidated)
        {
            strResult = null;
        }
        else
        {
            strResult = new Java.Lang.String(string.Empty);
        }
        return strResult;
    }
}
```